# EF6 Configuring a Required-to-Optional Relationship (One-to–Zero-or-One

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, relationship

I have two database tables called

SegmentSet
SegmentSetGeometry

They both have primary key called `SegmentSetId`. (The SegmentSetGeometry (dependent) segmentSetId is foreign key to SegmentSet (primary)).

SegmentSets can have 0 or 1 SegmentSetGeometries

I have two classes representing these tables called `SegmentSet` and `SegmentSetGeometry`:

```
public class SegmentSet
{
    public long SegmentSetId { get; set; }
    // ...
    public virtual SegmentSetGeometry SegmentSetGeometry { get; set; }
}

public class SegmentSetGeometry
{
    public long SegmentSetId { get; set; }
    public DbGeometry Geometry { get; set; }

    public virtual SegmentSet SegmentSet { get; set; }
}
```

Here are their configurations:

```
public class SegmentSetConfiguration: EntityTypeConfiguration<SegmentSet>
{
    public SegmentSetConfiguration()
    {
        ToTable("SegmentSet");
        HasKey(x => x.SegmentSetId);

        // ...

        HasOptional(x => x.SegmentSetGeometry)
            .WithRequired(x => x.SegmentSet);
    }
}

public class SegmentSetGeometryConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<SegmentSetGeometry>
{
    public SegmentSetGeometryConfiguration()
    {
        ToTable("SegmentSetGeometry");
        HasKey(x => x.SegmentSetId);
    }
}
```

When attempting to get a `SegmentSet` from the database the following error shows up:

`Invalid column name 'SegmentSet_SegmentSetId'.`

I found this reference https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/fluent/relationships and decided to switch the relationship and tried:

```
public class SegmentSetConfiguration: EntityTypeConfiguration<SegmentSet>
{
    public SegmentSetConfiguration()
    {
        ToTable("SegmentSet");
        HasKey(x => x.SegmentSetId);

        // ...
    }
}

public class SegmentSetGeometryConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<SegmentSetGeometry>
{
    public SegmentSetGeometryConfiguration()
    {
        ToTable("SegmentSetGeometry");
        HasKey(x => x.SegmentSetId);
        HasRequired(x => x.SegmentSet)
            .WithOptional(x=>x.SegmentSetGeometry);

    }
}
```

But still doesn't work. I am using the example they give and it's not working, and I have looked at all the similar stack overflows and still not working

Answer (score 0):

To map these two together, you should map from the required side of the relationship, and only that one side. Mapping both sides can lead to EF getting a bit garbled which may be causing your issue.

```
public class SegmentSet
{
    public long SegmentSetId { get; set; }
    // ...
    public virtual SegmentSetGeometry Geometry { get; set; }
}

public class SegmentSetGeometry
{
    public long SegmentSetId { get; set; }
    // ...
    public virtual SegmentSet SegmentSet { get; set; }
}

public class SegmentSetConfiguration: EntityTypeConfiguration<SegmentSet>
{
    public SegmentSetConfiguration()
    {
        ToTable("SegmentSets");
        HasKey(x => x.SegmentSetId);
        // Note: Do not map the HasOptional here... Only map the required on the other side.
    }
}

public class SegmentSetGeometryConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<SegmentSetGeometry>
{
    public SegmentSetGeometryConfiguration()
    {
        ToTable("SegmentSetGeometries");
        HasKey(x => x.SegmentSetId);
        HasRequired(x => x.SegmentSet)
            .WithOptional(x=>x.Geometry);

    }
}
```

That should work as expected using the PK's on each table for the 1..0/1 relationship.

Edit: It's also worth checking that the Entity configurations are being loaded. That might explain EF falling back on convention. In the DbContext:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    modelBuilder.Configurations.AddFromAssembly(GetType().Assembly);
}
```

The above assumes the Entity Type Configs are in the same assembly as the DbContext definition. Otherwise: `typeof(SegmentSetGeometryConfiguration).Assembly` would do the trick.

Comment: Sorry it probably wasn't clear from my question but after I read the document I removed the fluent API from the SegmentSetConfiguration, so I actually have exactly what you suggested and it's not working. I am thinking it may be related to the query and not the relastionship. I am going to update the question to be more clear

Comment: That is unusual because I set up the above table structure as a test and it works as expected without issue. The above is a copy & paste from the test project. What database engine are you using?  Also, are you sure the EntityTypeConfigs are being loaded? It could explain EF falling back on convention. (Edited answer to include that.)

Comment: What is the replacement for this relationship in EF Core